# Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: error during server startup?

Tags: java, oracle

Currently in one of our application we are getting below error :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call test_pkg.set_user_details(?)}?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2
```

Procedure Body :

```
 PROCEDURE set_user_details(ID NUMBER DEFAULT -1)
 IS
 BEGIN 

 //
 //
 END set_user_details;
```

There is no issue in Java or DB code. Same code is working since long time and there is no recent change.

From Java code we are passing single parameter to that stored proc.
This is an intermittent issue. It happens only when we restart the server. As per my knowledge this is happening because if we do any transaction during server startup,
DB and application can be in different state and those 2 will not be in sync. Please correct me if I am wrong.

My question is, **if its a state related issue, then why its giving `Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2` instead of giving state related error\exception ?**
Also, even though that stored proc accept only one param , that exception says parameter is missing at index 2. Why its expecting param at index 2 ?

Currently we are using Oracle 12c and using JdbcTemplate to execute stored proc

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with the prepared statement, it's `[{call test_pkg.set_user_details(?)}?)}];` but definitely should be `[{call test_pkg.set_user_details(?)}];` - somehow the part `?)}` gets doubled...

Comment: As I said that same code works if I dont restart the server

Comment: Yeah i know - but the prepared statement is still wrong that way - might be that the restart of the server causes that difference in the statement - i couldn't say that...